# Typescript dynamically properties typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

I have a class that takes an object that I want to set his properties to the **this** of the instance:

```
class Test {
  constructor(config) {
   for(let field in config) {
      this[field] = config[field];
    }
  }
}

const test = new Test({name: "JOHN", age: 13});
```

The config object is dynamic and can be any property; there is a way that I can get Intellisense after the initiation?

For example now when I am typing test and dot I want to get Intellisense as the config object properties were a member of the class.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not having the config as a member of the class?

Comment: This is a complicated answer. I just need to do that like this.

Comment: Well, with the limited information that you have provided the answer is that no, you won't be able to have type info (for the Intellisense ). If you want help with that you'll need to explain your problem/scenario.

Comment: I just explained in the question. I want to add properties dynamically to the instance.

Comment: If you don't know the properties in advance then what type info do you expect to get? If you know them when writing the code then they are not dynamic. You need to decide, or once again: explain your problem/scenario better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is a generic class with a generic property

```
class Test<T> {
  constructor(public config: T) { }
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const test = new Test<Person>({ name: "JOHN", age: 13 });

test.config.name
```

[image: intellisense]

See

- [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Types don't change your code, they are just design-time artifacts. Types will just "evaporate" when compiling, so there is no way for TypeScript to provide intellisense with something that happens on runtime.